# How do i give a user a role with '/' command with discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to give myself a role when executing a "/" command, and ive tryed many solutions from stackoverflow but none of them work for discord.js v14. Im pretty new to js.

tryed:

```
const guild = interaction.guild
const role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Admin');
var dcuser = interaction.user.id
dcuser.roles.add(role)
```

Got:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')

Answer (score 2):

The user.id (string) does not have .add(role) method

Try this

```js
const guild = interaction.guild
const role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Admin'); // Find role named "Admin" in cached roles
const member = interaction.member; // Guild member
await member.roles.add(role); // Add role to member
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Discord.js v14`, the roles property is not directly accessible on the User object. Instead, you need to get the `GuildMember` object for the user and then use the roles property on that object to add or remove roles.

Here's how you can give a user a role with a slash command:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('giverole')
    .setDescription('Give a user a role.')
    .addUserOption(option =>
      option.setName('user')
        .setDescription('The user to give the role to.')
        .setRequired(true))
    .addRoleOption(option =>
      option.setName('role')
        .setDescription('The role to give to the user.')
        .setRequired(true)),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const guild = interaction.guild;
    const member = guild.members.cache.get(interaction.options.getUser('user').id);
    const role = interaction.options.getRole('role');

    try {
      await member.roles.add(role);
      await interaction.reply(`The role ${role.name} has been added to ${member.user.username}.`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      await interaction.reply('There was an error giving the role.');
    }
  },
};
```